# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'. Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5uxu.png)
I don't know what's problem

Comment: Hi, if you are based in Iran or china (or any country under restrictions by google, Gradle ...), follow these steps: use a VPN or IP changer, delete the android folder of the project, and run ( flutter create . ) in the root of the project, then run the project.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.